# map dont load on cellphone web application

Tags: web-applications, phonegap-build, mapbox, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I used Intel XDK and PhoneGap to build a hybrid web application but after I built it and install it on Android 4.2.2 it runs but the map wont load on it.  I used MapBox for the map and when I try it on the pc it loads but it wont on the cellphone. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

check the whitelist of your project you must add or define the external access of your apk. PROJECT->BUILD SETTINGS ->WHITELIST.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/articles/cordova-cli-412-domain-whitelisting-with-intel-xdk-for-ajax-and-launching-external-apps

Comment: Just check that and it has * (all allow it), i think it has to be with the android version, because im using the MapboxGL but when i try the Mapbox js it works